# How to get validation errors in an array?

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I am developing an REST API using Codeigniter.
I need to have all error messages from Form validation in array format so that
I can easily respond in either JSON or XML.

Right now Codeigniter is delivering error messages with `<p>` as delimiters (see below)
but that is not good for a REST based API.

```
<p>There was an error with this item</p>
```

How can I get errors in an array?

Thankful for all input!

Comment: Tags. They don't go in titles.

Comment: Probably the Codeigniter Form module is not flexible enough for your purpose. Is replacing it with a more flexible implementation an option for you?

Comment: Perhaps. Do you know of any good alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form validation library stores errors in an array and loops through them to generate the error string.  They are stored in a private variable called `$_error_array`.  You could extend the library with a simple method that returns the error array.

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation
{
    function get_error_array()
    {
        return $this->_error_array;
    }
}
```

I assume you are familiar with extending core CI libraries, but this extension of the form validation library will give you a method to return the errors as an array with the name attribute's value as the key and the message as the value.  I tested it out on one of my projects and it worked fine.

Comment: Interesting! How would such an extension look like?

Comment: Cool! How do I use it in my controller?

Comment: Never mind. Got it, thank you so much! This is how I access it in my controller: $this->form_validation->get_error_array()

Comment: This code works perfectly fine on my local server (Mac) but on the remote server I get a 500 error. What can be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can transform it easily:

```
/**
 * @param $errors string
 * @return array
 */
function transformErrorsToArray ($errors) {
    $errors = explode('</p>', $errors);
    foreach ($errors as $index => $error) {
        $error = str_replace('<p>', '', $error);
        $error = trim($error);
        // ... more cleaning up if necessary
        $errors[$index] = $error
    }
    return $errors;
}
```

Comment: Looking good but it adds an empty "slot" in the array at the end of it. How can I leave that out? Array
(
    [0] => The Number field is required.
    [1] => 
)

Comment: I like this answer more than the accepted one, as it doesn't require you to change the CodeIgniter core code